# Reading a web page with python but question marks appear instead of apostrophes

Tags: python, html

Hi I'm trying to get all the content from `http://services.runescape.com/m=news/recruit-a-friend-for-free-membership-and-xp` INCLUDING links, but not some other stuff. What I've done currently is:

```
import urllib
url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=news/recruit-a-friend-for-free-membership-and-xp"
a = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
b = a.split("<div class=\"Content\">")[1]
c = b.split("</div>")[0]
print c
```

This prints: http://pastebin.com/WFXGpvRu

I've been doing lots of `replace()`'s to remove some stuff, such as remove the `<p>`s (*which I don't want*) and change `<b>` to '' (*That's two apostrophes there*).

But the problem I'm at is the question marks. When there's supposed to be an apostrophe, question marks appear. I can't just do a `replace()` because there are question marks there which are supposed to be there and not supposed to be apostrophes.

Is there a simpler way to do everything I've done?

Comment: **Moderator Note** _Comments under this question have been purged because they were purely useless noise. Please keep comments constructive and on topic_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those apostrophes aren't regular ASCII quotes, but rather, WINDOWS-1252 single quotes. They appear as question marks when your print because c is a "str" (binary string) which needs to be decoded.

Do this extra step in the end:

```
d = c.decode("windows-1252")
print d
```

d is now a unicode object containing the text you want.

Comment: "Was this post helpful to you" I clicked yes. I tried voting up, but it said I needed reputation

Comment: under the downvote arrow of this post, you see a check symbol (the "v"), just click on that to accept the answer.

Comment: Pretty new to contributing on SO - can someone tell me why I got downvoted on this answer?

Comment: @tommy It was probably a trollvote by someone. I voted you up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML with string operations is generally not a recommendable idea. There is a variety of python libraries that help you with parsing HTML:

Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) ([here](http://kochi-coders.com/?p=122), have a straightforward tutorial) or [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).